# MATLAB maximum value

Tags: matlab, max

I have a question regarding `max` command in MATLAB

let's say I have `x` and `y` matrices:

```
x = [1 2 3 4 5 6  7 8  9]
y = [1 4 6 2 3 64 7 67 6]
```

Now, I know how to find `x` value at which `y` is maximum

```
xIndex = find(y==max(y));
maxXValue = x(xIndex);
```

something like this..

My questions are:

- Do I have to `plot(x, y)` in order to find `x` value at which `y` is max?
- Is there any way I can find that value without plotting?
- I would like to find it without plotting (or at least plot but not actually show it)

Answer (score 1):

The second output of [`max`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html)/[`min`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/min.html) is the index in the array at which that value occurs. Assuming `x` and `y` share indices you can use this to map between the two.

For example:

```
x = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9];
y = [1 4 6 2 3 64 7 67 6];

[miny, minidx] = min(y);
[maxy, maxidx] = max(y);

fprintf('Ymin: %d, Xval: %u\nYmax: %d, Xval: %u\n', miny, x(minidx), maxy, x(maxidx))
```

Returns:

```
Ymin: 1, Xval: 1
Ymax: 67, Xval: 8
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use logical indexing to get the x value(s) corresponding to the maximum y directly like this:

```
x(y==max(y))
```

If there are duplicate maximum values of `y` then you will get each matching/corresponding value of `x` as well.